# Handling NIC settings with UWF in Windows 10 enterprise

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter, uwf

We are using UWF to protect our Windows 10 IoT Enterprise LTSB machines which run in a kiosk mode with our own software.

For the latest product, we have made a software shell/wrapper around the WMI Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class. Now the user can change the IP settings of a NIC. However, in order to remember the settings after a reboot, we have to commit the changes to the volume.

UWF doesn't provide a "commit all" function anymore like EWF. So who can tell me which part of the registry of file I have to commit in order to store the changes? I've searched for a long time but can't find the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, just add the following registry key to the exclusions:

```
uwfmgr registry add-exclusion "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces"
```